# swiftc Segmentation fault 11 saying "While emitting IR SIL function"

Tags: swift, xcode

Archiving iOS project makes swiftc throw segmentation fault 11. I just updated to xcode 11.5, swift v5.2.4. Project builds and runs on emulator. The exact error message is "3. While emitting IR SIL function" and the function code is below that this error is pointing to the function name. Can someone point whats wrong with new version as the code was working before update Xcode and swift.

```
func startC() {
  if let controller = self as? MyProtocol {
    if !startRandomizer() {
        controller.finished()
    } else {
        controller.sendComm(to:nil)
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: If you just updated xcode, ensure that your command line tools are up to date and pointing at the right app directory using `xcode-select`. Also try delete your xcode DerivedData and restarting xcode

Comment: yes, deleted DerievedData and rebuild, results to same error while archiving.